# Find an equation for the plane passing though the tips of u, v and w

Tags: vectors

Consider the vectors u = (3, 1, 0) and v = (3, 0, 1)
Find an equation for the plane passing though the tips of u, v and w:

I know the cross product of these 2 vectors = (1,-3,-3)

How do I go from there ?

Comment: What is $w$? $ \ $

Comment: its 3 vectors u and v and w

Comment: according to my previous answer vector w is perpendicular to both vector u and v - (1,-3,-3) which is the cross product of vector u and v.

Comment: u = (3,1,0) and v = (3,0,1) and w = (1,-3,-3)

Answer (score 1):

If you start at the origin, you can follow one vector, to get to one point on the plane, say for example

$$\overrightarrow v$$

That's very exciting.

Let's again start from the origin, go to where $v$ is pointing, but then go back to the origin (which I denote with an arrow in the opposite direction) and then back to a point on the plane again, by going along another vector, say $u$ for example

$$\overrightarrow v+\overleftarrow v + \overrightarrow u$$

Great.

Except, isn't "going in the opposite direction" also denoted with a minus like so
$$v - v + u$$
which simplifies to just $u$? Yes, going to where $v$ points and then back is rather pointless. Or is it? Is there another way? If the simplification is not applied, the latter two vectors can be considered representign another one, which points from the tip of $v$ to the tip of $u$

$$\overrightarrow v+\underbrace{\overleftarrow v + \overrightarrow u}$$
$$\overrightarrow v+\overrightarrow {vu}$$

The journey now goes from the origin to where $v$ is pointing. But after that, instead of returning to the origin, the path continues directly to where $u$ is pointing. The reached goal is still where $u$ is pointing to. The difference is that the new vector $vu$ lies on the plane. That's because both $v$ and $u$ point to points on the plane, which makes all points in between them points on the plane as well.

The line between the two tips of the vectors can be extended arbitrarily, which can be denoted with a scalar variable in front of the directional vector $vu$

$$\overrightarrow v+a~\overrightarrow {vu}$$

That variable conencts the two "endpoints" or the vectors to a line and also expands that line to $\pm\infty$.

Doing the same thing with the third vector $w$ expands that line to a second dimension, which will in fact turn it into a plane.

It doesn't matter what combination of existing vectors you choose to define the second directional vector as long as it isn't in line with the first one $vu$. One example could be to go from $v$ to $w$ similarly to the first case

$$\overrightarrow v+a~\overrightarrow {vu}+b~\overrightarrow {vw}$$

If you want to get rid of the arrow notation, it would look something like this

$$v+a(u-v)+b(w-v)$$

Let's call this plane $p$ and write some more things about some of the used letters, because mathematicians really like that.

$$p=v+a(u-v)+b(w-v)$$
$$a,b\in \mathbb{R}$$
$$p, v,u,w \in \mathbb{R}^3$$

$p$ is the plane that goes through the tips of the vectors $u$,$v$ and $w$.

Answer (score 0):

The scalar equation of the plane would be in the form Ax+By+Cz+D=0.

A, B, C are simply 1, -3 and -3 respectively (the normal vector). D is calculated as: -(normal vector)dot(any point on the plane).

Ex. -(1, -3, -3)dot(3, 1, 0)=0=D

Therefore, x-3y-3z=0 is the scalar equation of this plane.

Comment: So it would work exactly the same as the following question:   Find an equation for the plane containing u and v ? which will also give x -3y -3z = 0 ? they do not specify any points so I assume it goes through (0,0,0)

Comment: Usually, we use the point given (if possible) though because D usually has a value. (this is a special case where D=0)

Comment: So if no point is given it means (0,0,0) and D = 0 ?

Comment: No. As the vectors u and v lie on the plane... Use their position vectors to give the points (3, 1, 0) and (3, 0, 1). Try solving for D with either of those points and it will give you D=0. Do not assume the point on the plane is (0, 0, 0)

Comment: I see D = (1,-3,-3).(ANY POINT) (3,0,1) or (3,1,0) = 0

Comment: So if this was any other case D would equal a point on the plane but in this special case it = 0 ?

Comment: No, my bad. I misunderstood your previous comment. Calculate D as my answer shows. Yes, in this case, D=0

Comment: Try finding the equation of the plane given two direction vectors: (1, 2, 1) and (-2, 3, 1) and a point (5, 1, 2)

Comment: answer should be: x+3y-7z+6=0

Comment: Cross Product = (-1,-3,7) do I now use the point as my (x0,y0,z0) or do I use or can I use the vector points ? I get -x -3y +7z =0

Comment: no! use the given point (5, 1, 2)

Comment: I get -x -3y -7z + 6 =0 if I use the point (5,1,3)

Comment: in other words x +3y +7z -6 = 0 ?

Comment: Close. D is calculated as the negative dot product of the normal and the point. (-1, -3, 7)dot(5, 1, 2)=6. you need to make it negative.. therefore D= -6. Your equation becomes -x-3y+7z-6=0. move everything to the other side to get x+3y-7z+6=0

Comment: why do I need to make it negative ?

Comment: because D is the negative dot product of the normal and the point (as per my answer above)

Comment: I see thanks, I like challenges but I am new to Linear Algebra and Calculus A. I am struggling because I study part time. Do you have experience in De Moivre’s Theorem as well ?

Comment: I recommend researching (even on Google your topic). This way you'll be exposed to all the tricks that are difficult to fully explain via text here. Personally, I watch videos on the topic by as many trusted professors as possible and attempting around 50-100 questions on the topic before feeling comfortable. Try that and feel free to open a new question on StackExchange if another question stumps you again.

Comment: I wish you good luck on your studies. Remember, research is part of the adventure in learning!! (that is how knowledge was developed) Research allows you to relive the work of many geniuses in the past!

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly do so.